# Power Apps Premium License Vs Power Automate Premium License? is there any overlap between them

Tags: office-365, power-automate, powerapp, licensing, power-platform

I am a bit confused on what does Power App Premium license gives us inside Power Automate? and what does Power Automate Premium License gives us inside Power Apps? for example if a user has a Power Automate Premium license , then the user can call a custom connector from Power Apps? or connect a Power Apps with Dataverse? on the other side, for example if a user has Power Apps Premium license, then the user can call external http using automated flow or scheduled flow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Power Apps Premium` license is the new name for `Power Apps per user` license (`Power Apps per app` is still an option). Similary, `Power Automate Premium` is the new name of `Power Automate per user`.

[`Power Apps Premium`](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) includes the premium connectors of Power Automate, Dataverse, Power Pages and credits for AI Builder. It's about 20 $USD/user/month. [`Power Automate Premium`](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) is cheaper (15 $USD/user/month), includes RPA, process mining and more AI Builder credits, but does not include Power Pages.

No need to have both license, you must choose depending your need for Power Pages, AI Builder or RPA. As each license provides a number of execution per day, **in some scenario**, it could be useful to combine both license for a single user to increase the [daily quota/requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/api-request-limits-allocations).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. So let say i have a Power Apps Premium license, then i can not create a scheduled flow which connect to SQL or connect to dataverse or send http request to external system? am i correct? in this case i will need Power Automate Premium license? i mean Power Apps premium allow us to create premium flows only if the flows are going to be called from power apps? is this the case?

Comment: Yes, you can. There is no "technical" limitation but "functional" limitation: your flow (scheduled, for example) must be related with the use case of your Power Apps. So, for example, you can add the Power Apps and the flow to same solution, even if the Power Apps does not have a direct call to the flow. Power Apps Premium license includes `"Power Automate use rights (including premium connectors) / Trigger flows within the context of the app."`

Comment: i do not think this is the case,

Comment: same context means flows that are been called from the app, and does not mean within the same solution

Comment: No, same context does not mean the flow must be called by the Power Apps. A scheduled flow cannot be called by a Power Apps as it's ...scheduled. It means the business use case is the same.